# Use Spring Native with custom Docker registry

Tags: docker, gradle, buildpack, spring-native

We're experimenting with Spring Native, following their [guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-buildpacks). Additionally, we wish use Gradle and [Buildpacks](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.6/reference/html/features.html#container-images.buildpacks). We have adapted our configuration (`build.gradle`) accordingly and run `./gradlew bootBuildImage` in order to build the Spring Native image.

The problem arises because we are forced to use the custom Docker image registry of our company. Therefore, we can't directly pull e. g. `docker.io/paketobuildpacks/run:tiny-cnb`, but have to use something like `docker-io.docker-proxy.ourcompany.com/paketobuildpacks/run:tiny-cnb`.

We have already pulled and re-tagged the builder image `paketobuildpacks/builder` used during the process. But as the rest is happening *inside* this build container, we cannot use this solution any further. So we get:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootBuildImage'.
> Docker API call to 'localhost/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=docker.io%2Fpaketobuildpacks%2Frun%3Atiny-cnb' failed with status code 500 "Internal Server Error" and message "Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": context deadline exceeded"
```

(Probably because a connection attempt to `*.docker.io` will just time out.)

As of the moment, we have not found a possibility to configure the Docker registry used by the process. We could also find a bigger "tree" of further dependencies needed later during the process, described in files like [here](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/java-native-image/blob/main/package.toml) (where `gcr.io` is referred instead of `docker.io`).

In no way will we be allowed to access the public registries directly and thus have no further ideas. So, can you think of any sane possibility to achieve our goal of building the Spring Native image using your our own proxy registries?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check the official documentation https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/?

Comment: @SergioSantiago, thank you, yes, we thought about this solution. But it's not the proxy we're missing, but the custom registry "redirect". Trying to enter our company registry as proxy server in the config mentioned did not make any difference. (Also, our company registry needs to be accessed via hostname in order to work properly... :( )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `pack` cli, you can run `pack config registry-mirrors add <registry> [-m <mirror...] [flags]`, ex: `pack config registry-mirrors add index.docker.io --mirror 10.0.0.1` where `10.0.0.1` is your private registry.

https://buildpacks.io/docs/tools/pack/cli/pack_config_registry-mirrors_add/

In Spring Boot's Gradle support you have the `docker.builderRegistry` and `docker.publishRegistry` settings, but these are primarily used to supply credentials to be used to fetch or publish images from the registry. They do not quite do what we need here.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.7/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.docker-registry

Support for mirror functionality, like with `pack` cli, isn't presently an option. An [issue has been opened to track support for this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/30852), so hopefully it'll be available in a future release.

In the meantime, you can use `pack` cli with the mirror option above to build images.

A quick way to test/validate:

1. Run `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name=registry -e REGISTRY_PROXY_REMOTEURL=https://registry-1.docker.io registry:2`. This will run a local registry that [mirrors Docker Hub](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/).
2. Run `pack config registry-mirrors add '*' --mirror localhost:5000` to tell `pack` cli to use the registry mirror.
3. Run `pack build` against your app. You should see output like:

```
Using mirror localhost:5000/paketobuildpacks/builder:base for index.docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:base
base: Pulling from paketobuildpacks/builder
83525de54a98: Pulling fs layer
807f554cf05f: Pulling fs layer
...
```

If you see that line, you know it's working properly.

You should also see this in your `pack` config:

```
> cat ~/.pack/config.toml
[registry-mirrors]
  "*" = "localhost:5000"
```

That means you've got the registry mirror set up correctly.

Comment: Thank you, @Daniel Mikusa, but there are two drawback to this solution. :( The block in the `build.gradle` really makes it download the builder image from our custom registry. But then I get: `Execution failed for task ':bootBuildImage'.
> Run image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/run:tiny-cnb' must be pulled from the 'docker-io.docker-proxy.ourcompany.com' authenticated registry`. Which I don't understand, because that's exactly what happened, I can even find the image then using `docker images` (after having pruned the Docker system before).

Comment: We had also thought about he pack cli solution, but we would need to apply this setting _within_ the build container - and there is no pack cli in that builder image. :(

Comment: And another addition: The gradle exception from my first comment only occurs in conjuction with `bootBuildImage {builder = "docker-remote-docker-io.artifacts.ruv.de/paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny"}` in our `build.gradle`. If I remove this setting, the process will fail because of not reaching `docker.io` again.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to ask about the Gradle config. I went to test and it's requiring me to have creds even through our internal docker cache is not password protected. In terms of `pack` cli, you should be able to use that you don't need it in the builder. You just need pack cli on your build machine, basically wherever you run `./gradlew bootBuildImage`. Instead of running `./gradlew bootBuildImage`, you run `pack build`.

Comment: Sorry for being late to reply! I had also faced the credentials problem but could get around it using some valid credentials. I also tried your solution with `pack config...`, but the problem persists without any change when using it. :(

Comment: I updated this with some notes on Spring Boot's support. I don't think it's going to work as is now, but there's an issue open now to support it. As far as pack, I added more details to my answer. Those steps should work. I verified them & provided steps to test/verify as well. If you're not having any luck with pack, I would suggest you open a new question since this one was directed at Spring Boot's support. Feel free to mention me on that question.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and great professional help! I cannot give it a try until next week, but as you said, it's mainly a Spring Boot problem, so I regard my question answered.